# Register all user defined functions

Tags: php, twig

I need a little work around this thing. I'm trying to register all my defined functions in twig. I used the code below trying to achieve my goal but it doesn't work.
Inside my test.twig I called one defined function 
                {{ site_url() }} 
but I get this error : Unknown "site_url" function.
I don't know what's wrong because I can easily print the list of all my defined functions inside my foreach as follows : 
                echo $v . "\n";

Here's my phone syntax

```
        // ALL USER FUNCTIONS 

        $arr = get_defined_functions(); 

         foreach ($arr['user'] as $k => $v){
            // $this->_twig is my twig loader

            return $this->_twig->addFunction(
    new Twig_SimpleFunction(
    $v,
    $v
    ));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is obsolete, now you are only registering the first user defined function

```
$arr = get_defined_functions(); 
foreach ($arr['user'] as $v){
    // $this->_twig is my twig loader
    $this->_twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction($v, $v));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still have the twig syntax error stating that site_url function is unknown.